# How to make a form fixed in it's position on background image slider

Tags: jquery, css

I'm designing a website,where in the **index page** there should be **image slider**

there will be a **registration form** on the **image slider**,I want that the slider images will slide but the form will not slide,it will be in it's same position.

But I can't do that and I have no idea that how should I do that.

Please help me out.Thanks in advance.

Comment: This site is meant to answer specific questions, not develop a site for you. We're more than happy to help, but either... **a) Provide what you have so far**, or **b) [Read this - How To Ask](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask)**

Comment: Hard to tell what you mean. Give us your code.

If you can set your slider to relative. and Absolutely position your form over the top of it? Have you tried that?

Answer (score 0):

as to my comment above. Its hard to tell with out your giving us your code. Cheers

```
[JSfiddle][1]
```

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gorelegacy/6SG3B/)

EDIT:

In your HTML create a container div around your slider. Inside your container div, move the form out of the slider into container

```
<div class="container">

<div class="form"> <input type="text"> <input type="text"> <input type="submit"> </div>

<div class="slider"><ul class="cb-slideshow"> <li> <div><a href="javascript:void(0)"><img src="img/ABHIK.jpg"></a></div> </li> <li> <div><a href="javascript:void(0)"><img src="img/skytel_night.jpg"></a></div> </li> <li> <div><a href="javascript:void(0)"><img src="img/skytel_afternoon.jpg"></a></div> </li> </ul> </div>

<div> <---container-end--->
```

In your CSS, try `.container {position: relative}` and `.form {position: absolute; right: 0px; bottom: 0px}`

Give that a crack, but the code you provided is pretty limited. If you have it on the web or a JSfiddle i could try give you a solution.

Comment: <div class="slider">
    <div class="form">
        <input type="text">
        <input type="text">
        <input type="submit">
 </div>

    <ul class="cb-slideshow">
      <li>
        <div><a href="javascript:void(0)"><img src="img/ABHIK.jpg"></a></div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div><a href="javascript:void(0)"><img src="img/skytel_night.jpg"></a></div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div><a href="javascript:void(0)"><img src="img/skytel_afternoon.jpg"></a></div>
      </li>
    </ul>
</div>

Comment: this is my code..the images will slide and the form div remain in its original position.